# Laravel Blade Template @extends

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In my views i am extending a `default` blade template which acts as my **Master Template**. I have a ViewComposer setup which serves this template with a number of variables.

I have come to a situation where i need to access one of these variables within my `index.blade.php` which is the page initiating the `@extends` function.

Do the variable passed via the ViewComposer reach the scope of the initial view? Or will i need to create another ViewComposer to pass the same variable.

### ViewComposer

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\View\View;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Repositories\UserRepository;
use Sentinel;
use App\ProjectUsers;

class MasterComposer
{
    /**
     * The user repository implementation.
     *
     * @var UserRepository
     */
    protected $users;
    private $request;

    /**
     * Create a new profile composer.
     *
     * @param  UserRepository  $users
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {

        $this->request = $request;
        // Dependencies automatically resolved by service container...
        $uid = Sentinel::getUser()->id;
        $this->users = ProjectUsers::where("user_id", '=', $uid)->get();
    }

    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('projects', $this->users);
        $view->with('activeProject', $this->request->session()->get("activeProject"));
    }
}
```

### ComposerServiceProvider

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot() {
        // Using class based composers...
        view ()->composer ( 'admin/layouts/default', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\MasterComposer' );
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register() {
        //
    }
}
```

### index.blade.php

```
@extends('admin/layouts/default')
{{ $activeProject }}
```

This ultimately give me an undefined variable error.

```
Undefined variable: activeProject (View: /home/laravel/public_html/base/resources/views/admin/index.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all variables which are available in the master layout will be passed to any of its children.

Comment: As stated in my question. I am not using `@include` I'm using `@extends`

Comment: All variables will be passed in both cases.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case in my Application

Comment: This is at the top of my `index.blade.php` : `@extends('admin/layouts/default')`

Comment: Post appropriate code please. Maybe we could help you then.

Comment: Added the relevant parts including my Composer

Comment: Try `@extends('admin.layouts.default')`

Comment: There isn't any issue with the view actually being loaded properly. Just can't access a variable from the `default` template, in the `index` template

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using @extends in your content layout you can use this

`@extends('admin/layouts/default', ['activeProject' => $activeProject])`

If this doesn't work you might need to pass it through your controller